# Why would one want multiple locks within the same data structure?

Tags: concurrency, locking, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I've been studying some [existing C code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-wiimote.h) [for a device driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-wiimote-core.c) I want to write. It is my first time dealing with concurrency and locking and also the first time I've dealt with anything hardware-related like device drivers. I found a piece of code that seems to use multiple locks for the same data structure. I'm wondering why would anyone include two different locking structures (both a spinlock and a mutex) within the *same* data structure instead of just a single lock that locks the entire data structure?

```
struct wiimote_state {
    spinlock_t lock;
    __u32 flags;
    __u8 accel_split[2];
    __u8 drm;
    __u8 devtype;
    __u8 exttype;
    __u8 mp;

    /* synchronous cmd requests */
    struct mutex sync;
    struct completion ready;
    int cmd;
    __u32 opt;

    /* results of synchronous requests */
    __u8 cmd_battery;
    __u8 cmd_err;
    __u8 *cmd_read_buf;
    __u8 cmd_read_size;

    /* calibration/cache data */
    __u16 calib_bboard[4][3];
    __s16 calib_pro_sticks[4];
    __u8 pressure_drums[7];
    __u8 cache_rumble;
};
```

An example of a code snippet using these multiple locks:

```
static void wiimote_init_detect(struct wiimote_data *wdata)
{
    __u8 exttype = WIIMOTE_EXT_NONE, extdata[6];
    bool ext;
    int ret;

    wiimote_cmd_acquire_noint(wdata);

    spin_lock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);
    wdata->state.devtype = WIIMOTE_DEV_UNKNOWN;
    wiimote_cmd_set(wdata, WIIPROTO_REQ_SREQ, 0);
    wiiproto_req_status(wdata);
    spin_unlock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);

    ret = wiimote_cmd_wait_noint(wdata);
    if (ret)
        goto out_release;

    spin_lock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);
    ext = wdata->state.flags & WIIPROTO_FLAG_EXT_PLUGGED;
    spin_unlock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);

    if (!ext)
        goto out_release;

    wiimote_cmd_init_ext(wdata);
    exttype = wiimote_cmd_read_ext(wdata, extdata);

out_release:
    wiimote_cmd_release(wdata);
    wiimote_init_set_type(wdata, exttype);

    /* schedule MP timer */
    spin_lock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);
    if (!(wdata->state.flags & WIIPROTO_FLAG_BUILTIN_MP) &&
        !(wdata->state.flags & WIIPROTO_FLAG_NO_MP))
        mod_timer(&wdata->timer, jiffies + HZ * 4);
    spin_unlock_irq(&wdata->state.lock);
}

static inline void wiimote_cmd_acquire_noint(struct wiimote_data *wdata)
{
    mutex_lock(&wdata->state.sync);
}

static inline void wiimote_cmd_release(struct wiimote_data *wdata)
{
    mutex_unlock(&wdata->state.sync);
}
```

Comment: For example, `mutex` can’t be used in atomic contexts. Another possibility is to split hardware accesses and the rest stuff more granular.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things going on here.

First, don't think of the spinlock and the mutex as necessarily being "for" the data structure, just because they are "in" the data structure. In this case the spinlock appears to be what you describe, a lock for accessing the data structure. The mutex seems to be a lock for the action of commanding the wiimote.

Next, spinlocks and mutexes are quite different, the key being that mutexes are blocking and spinlocks poll until the resource is available.

Finally, although that's not what I see here, a module could contain both spinlocks and mutexes doing a similar function, if they were implemented at different times by different developers.